# Unique value for one columns in SELECT JOIN MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an query where user can pull data from two table with `JOIN`. but I would like one columns in the result to be specific to the `user_id` or return `null` if it doesn't match the `user_id`.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
        posts.id, 
        posts.deviceID, 
        posts.type, 
        posts.title,  
        posts.time, 
        SUM(value) AS votes,
        value AS userVote, <--- THIS NEED TO BE UNIQUE TO WHAT THE USER ID IS.          
        FROM posts 
        LEFT JOIN votes 
        on (posts.id = votes.post_id)
        GROUP BY posts.id
```

As you can see there is SELECT statement of `value AS userVote`. the function provides `user_id` with php `$_POST['user_id']` method, I know how to input this value. the query is confusing to me a little.

**Result in snapshot:**

[image]

Also, sorry in advance if this is duplicated question, but I can't think of what this method is called in MySQL query, if you can tell me I appreciate it.

**UPDATE:**

Currently I can get the value correctly with `CASE WHEN votes.user_id = 'USERID' THEN value END AS userVote` Thanks to one answer, but when there are two values it wouldn't return user value but `null`.

**Update Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: a column with `case when` or `if`

Comment: @Drew yes, what is the query and how can i do it in join statement? i really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.id, p.deviceID, p.type, p.title, p.time, 
       SUM(v.value) AS votes,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.user_id = u.user_id THEN v.value END) as userVote
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     votes v
     on p.id = v.post_id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Note:  if a user could vote multiple times, you might want `SUM()` or `GROUP_CONCAT()`, depending on what you want to see.

Comment: spot on..i couldn't get that

Comment: @NSGod . . . Actually, you are using a MySQL extension that allows columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  If you used any other database, your query would generate syntax errors, and you probably would have stumbled on this yourself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Intersting, yeah but I'm sticking to MySQL. I'm flexible with usage but not advanced yet. :)

Comment: @NSGod . . . You can set up the server to use the "standard" `GROUP BY`, by using `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I will read the document and change it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
posts.id, 
posts.deviceID, 
posts.type, 
posts.title,  
posts.time, 
SUM(value) AS votes,
-- value AS userVote,
case when posts.user_id = votes.user_id then value end as userVote,
case when posts.user_id = votes.user_id then post.user_id else null end AS UserIDVote           
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN votes 
on (posts.id = votes.post_id)
GROUP BY posts.id
```

Added a `case` condition which would work if both the tables have a `user_id` column. You would get `user_id` for all the matches and `null` otherwise.

Edit: If specific values are needed when there are matching userid's,  aggregation of values has to be excluded from the query.

```
SELECT 
posts.id, 
posts.deviceID, 
posts.type, 
posts.title,  
posts.time,
case when posts.user_id = votes.user_id then value end as userVote,
case when posts.user_id = votes.user_id then post.user_id else null end AS UserIDVote           
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN votes 
on posts.id = votes.post_id
```

Comment: do you mean `sum(value)` in the `select` statement. And if so, would you need the matching for only positive `sum(value)`?

Comment: I already get the total of votes, but i also want that columns userVote to be either 1 or -1 or `null` base on user_id

Comment: Your statement works, but sometime the value is -1 i need that if available

Comment: what are the possible values for `value` column?

Comment: values should either be 1, -1 or null

Comment: changed it..is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: this is correct `CASE WHEN posts.deviceID = votes.user_id THEN value END AS userVote`, but if there is 2 votes it will also return `null`

Comment: If is two votes and one match the user_id, it should return that

Comment: Kind of like this but that would return syntax error `CASE WHEN votes.user_id = AD8EABEC-9939-4665-930E-15BB4BACEA69 THEN value END AS userVote`

Comment: use quotes like `'AD8EABEC-9939-4665-930E-15BB4BACEA69'`

Comment: That still return null for 2 value vote. It won't return the user id one. This is so close

Comment: modified it..is that what you expect?

Comment: the sum value is correct, I have update the question please check.

Comment: if that is what you need, please take out the `sum(value)` from your query And also, the `group by` clause at the end

Comment: The sum is total value, but i also want the value of the user id itself and that would either be 1, -1 or null depending if they vote or not, but currently if 2 votes involve it would also return null

Comment: you can't do both of them in one query.

Comment: so basically i can't go to next available case of match user_id